# Icons.remove_red_eye Hide Show

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

## I would like it to show and hide when eyes are clicked

```
TextFormField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
  obscureText: true,
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    labelText: "Entrez votre mot de passe",
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
    suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye),
  ),
)
```

I would like it to show and hide when eyes are clicked

Answer (score 2):

Firstly need to declare a bool variable

```
bool passwordVisible = false;
```

Then in TextFormField you need to do following things

```
TextFormField(
   ...
   obscureText: !passwordVisible,//This will obscure text dynamically
   decoration: InputDecoration(
      ....
       suffixIcon: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              // Based on passwordVisible state choose the icon
               passwordVisible
               ? Icons.visibility
               : Icons.visibility_off,
               color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
               ),
            onPressed: () {
               //Toggle the state of passwordVisible variable
               setState(() {
                   passwordVisible = !passwordVisible;
               });
             },
            ),
          ),
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `TextFormField` is inside a `StatefulWidget`, create a variable `bool isPasswordVisible = false;` and use it as such:

```
TextFormField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
  obscureText: !isPasswordVisible,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "Entrez votre mot de passe",
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
    suffixIcon: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(isPasswordVisible
          ? Icons.visibility_off
          : Icons.visibility),
      onPressed: () => setState(() {
        isPasswordVisible = !isPasswordVisible;
      }),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this TextField:

Make sure that TextFormField is inside a StatefulWidget, create a variable bool _obscureText  = true; and use it as such:

```
SizedBox(
      height: 54,
      child: TextField(
        obscureText: _obscureText,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary, 
                width: 1),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          ),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          ),
          hintText: 'Password',
          suffixIcon: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _obscureText = !_obscureText;
              });
            },
            icon: _obscureText
                ? const Icon(Icons.visibility_off)
                : const Icon(Icons.visibility),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```